# Shopify: Displaying a list of all collections on collection page

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to make a clickable list of all collections on my collection page, but for some reason the following isn't working?

```
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% collection.title %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the problem that none title is displayed or about links (which is normal as you don't call for url in your code)? As it is, your code will only display a list of titles of collections available for the shop.

Comment: At the moment `{% collection.title %}` will not output anything since it should be `{{ collection.title }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output a variable with double curly braces, like this:  `{{ collection.title }}`

This snippet would give you a list of collections with links:

```
<ul>
{% for collection in collections %}
  <li>{{ collection.title | link_to: collection.url }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can learn more about Liquid syntax here: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/